# (PyQt5) Check the state of the UI and return True when something has changed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working with PyQt5 and wanted to know if there is a way to check to see if anything has changed in some way inside the UI.

In other words I want to see if any of these (QLineEdit, QCheckBox, QRadioButton, QSpinBox, QDoubleSpinBox, QSlider, QLabel, QComboBox, QListWidget) had changed in some way, and then run a function accordingly

Comment: What kind of changes do you mean?

Comment: Just any changes, so if something gets clicked on, or if something gets written in.

Comment: Delimit the changes you want to get because otherwise your question would be unsolvable.

Comment: Is there no way to use QEvent or something and just check for something changing?

Comment: In Qt changes are handled with events and signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to check for particular items that have been touched or manipulated in some way.

The function below will iterate and inspect all the members inside the UI and then check to see what has changed. You can then pass in an function argument and have it run whenever  one of these particular widgets get changed.

```
def isGuiChanged(self, ui, functionCall):
    try:
        for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(ui):
            if isinstance(obj, QLineEdit):
                obj.textChanged.connect(lambda: functionCall())

            if isinstance(obj, QCheckBox):
                obj.stateChanged.connect(lambda: functionCall())

            if isinstance(obj, QRadioButton):
                obj.toggled.connect(lambda: functionCall())

            if isinstance(obj, QSpinBox):
                obj.valueChanged.connect(lambda: functionCall())

            if isinstance(obj, QDoubleSpinBox):
                obj.valueChanged.connect(lambda: functionCall())

            if isinstance(obj, QSlider):
                obj.event.connect(lambda: functionCall())

            if isinstance(obj, QComboBox):
                obj.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: functionCall())

                # if isinstance(obj, QListWidget): This needs to be added at somepoint
                #     obj.

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```